# Abrir explorador de archivos con la ruta relativa de la carpeta en java

Tags: java

Estoy usando el siguiente codigo para abrir el explorador de archivos

```
try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe"," /select","./Documents\\EclipseProyectos\\Test").start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Pero con esto solo consigo entrar hasta documents no consigo que vaya a la carpeta test donde esta el proyecto

tambien he probado con

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe"," /select","Test").start();
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe"," /select","./Test").start();
```

Y demás pero siempre me abre Documentos, si no le pongo nada me abre mi pc

EDIT2:
Por ahora solo me funciona con ruta absoluta:

```
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select,C:\\Users\\nicoc\\Documents\\EclipseProyectos\\Test").start();
```

EDIT3:
Viendo que no consigo entrar en la carpeta se me ha ocurrido usar la ruta Path por medio de FileSystem

adjunto el codigo esta vez me deja en la carpeta de Eclipse pero no en Test que es la que quiero

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();//Creamos un File System para poder manejar ficheros
        
        Path home=fs.getPath("");
    
        try {
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select,"+home.toAbsolutePath()).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se queda así en el ultimo codigo que tengo puesto aqui con el metodo de FileSystem.  y en el path he hecho una salida por pantalla y esta bien escrita la ruta de hecho la he tenido que convertir a absoluta par aque me abriese al menos el EclipseProyect

Comment: Prueba con `Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe"," /select,.\\Documents\\EclipseProyectos\\Test").start();`

Comment: Sigue igual me abre la carpeta document

Comment: Podrias agregar un pantallazo de la ventana de explorador de windows que se te está abirendo al ejecutar el programa que contiene el codigo que estas publicando?

Comment: Ya puse captura

Comment: Que pena @GolpeCelestial, te pedi la captura anets de leer en tu edit que ya habias encontrado la solución utilizando ruta absoluta. Lo que queria ver era si realmente la carpeta Documents que te esta abriendo tenía en su interior la ruta a la que estabas intentando accesar dentro de ella. Te aconsejaría que, dado que tu mismop encontraste unas solucion la publicaras, no en tu pregunta, sino como una respuesta para saber al buscar que la pregunta ya fue respondida y aceptar tu respuesta para saber que ya tiene una respuesta aceptada. Saludos.

Comment: Si, pero no entra en la carpeta Test se queda en la anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cuestion es con el parametro `/select` este va a abrir el explorador de windows "y seleccionara el objeto que se le indica", para abrir el directorio hay que invocarlo sin el parametro `/select`. Intente con

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe","\".\\Documents\\EclipseProyectos\\Test\\\"").start();
```

Comment: Solo me habre documentos estoy probando ahora con otra cosa miralo por si puedes ayudarme solo me falta la ultima carpeta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la siguiente línea de código

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select," + path.trim());
```

Comment: Explica brevemente el código: lee [answer].